# How to convert character/factor to integer?

Tags: r

I know that has been asked quite frequently. However, by applying the previous advice I'm still confused about two things.

1. How to convert from multinomial values to integers?
2. How to get the integer back to the factor/character after the analysis?

   ```
     library(car)

     data(Prestige)
     View(Prestige)
     # here I convert directly from character which seems quite useless
     Prestige$TYPE<-as.numeric(levels(Prestige$type))
     # here I generate factors
     Prestige$type<-as.factor(Prestige$type)
     # and try to convert afterwards. doesnt work either
     Prestige$TYPE<-as.numeric(levels(Prestige$type))
   ```

Basically, I would like to extract the three levels in `type` without renaming it manually.

Comment: I don't understand.  Your example attempts to coerce letters to numbers... which makes no sense.

Comment: A factor contains 2 pieces of information - level values and level labels. One inefficient way to convert is to first associate the labels with the levels: `Prestige$type <- as.numeric(as.character(Prestige$type))`

Comment: Im trying to extract the three levels in type without renaming it manually.

Comment: "extract the three levels in type" = levels(Prestige$type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector with class `factor` has an attributes called `levels`.  The `levels` function acts on that attributes and *not* on the vector itself.

```
library(car)
data(Prestige)

length(Prestige$type) # 102

levels(Prestige$type) # Notice that this has length 3.
```

If you want the numeric values for the vector, use

```
as.numeric(Prestige$type)
```

What was `bc` is not `1`, what was `prof` is now `2`, and what was `wc` is now `3`.

if you need to reconstitute the factor, use

```
factor(Prestige$type, 1:3, c("bc", "prof", "wc"))
```

But as a general rule, it's better not to alter your factors unless you need to alter the categories.  If you need the numerical codes under the data, make a new variable

```
Prestige$type_numeric <- as.numeric(Prestige$type)
```

Comment: `as.numeric(Prestige$type)` `Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion`  Thats the reason why Im here :)

Comment: try clearing the workspace.  You probably have `Prestige$type` stored as something other than the original.  `rm(list = "Prestige")`.  and then try again.

Comment: Nope...rerun still the same